# Powershell - Strange result when exporting disk space result to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, diskspace

I have the following code that finds the free space on a drive on a server called 'Automate' and outputs the result to a .csv file:

```
$AutomateD = @()

Clear-Host

$AutomateD += Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName Automate ` | Where-Object {$_.VolumeName -ne 'Logs' -and $_.DeviceID -eq 'D:'}| Format-Table DeviceID, MediaType, `
@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.size/1gb))}}, `
@{Name="Free Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.freespace/1gb))}}, `
@{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}} `
-AutoSize

$AutomateD | Export-Csv -path "C:\Powershell\Automate\AutomateD.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode
$ImportAutoD = Import-CSV C:\Powershell\Automate\AutomateD.csv | ConvertTo-Html
```

The issue is that I get some strange results when I open the csv -

"ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd","pageHeaderEntry","pageFooterEntry","autosizeInfo","shapeInfo","groupingEntry"
"033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280",,,"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.AutosizeInfo","Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo",
"9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3",,,,,
"27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c",,,,,
"4ec4f0187cb04f4cb6973460dfe252df",,,,,
"cf522b78d86c486691226b40aa69e95c",,,,,

However, if I just output the `$AutomateD` variable on the screen, I get a nice table like so:

```
PS C:\Powershell\SCRIPT> $AutomateD

DeviceID MediaType Size(GB) Free Space(GB) Free (%)
-------- --------- -------- -------------- --------
D:              12     1225            183    15%
```

Any ideas as to what is going on? There seems to be an problem in the export process, although I don't have any errors to go on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `Format-Table` -> `Select-Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the format-table and replace it with a select-object.  You'll also need to drop the -autosize from the end of your pipeline.  In addition it is not required but I would recommend dropping the kind odd array creation and then adding a single value to the array, the script can actually get done in a single pipeline with the exception of the import-csv (which I'm not really sure you need but I'll leave it in assuming it's required elsewhere in the script)

```
Clear-Host

Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk ` | Where-Object {$_.VolumeName -ne 'Logs' -and $_.DeviceID -eq 'D:'}| Select-Object DeviceID, MediaType, `
@{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.size/1gb))}}, `
@{Name="Free Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f($_.freespace/1gb))}}, `
@{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f(($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}} |
Export-Csv -path d:\scripts\test.csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Unicode -Force

$ImportAutoD = Import-CSV d:\scripts\test.csv | ConvertTo-Html
```

Also note that I did make some path changes to make it work on my machine without building out a new folder structure.

Comment: Thankyou, that worked perfectly. Just to clarify, the import-csv is needed elsewhere when writing the e-mail body.

Answer (score -1):

when exporting the csv use -NoTypeInformation

Comment: He is already using  that, as you can see it in the code posted by him